# How to download a csvBlob?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created a csvBlob that contains user records,

Can someone please tell me how to download that file?

Thanks

Here is the code:

```
public with sharing class Send_noti_emails {


   public PageReference download_csv() {
         string header = 'Record Id, First Name , Last Name , Email, Qulification \n';
         string finalstr = header ;
         string recordString;

  for (Inquery__c inquery: [SELECT Email__c,First_Name__c, Last_Name__c,Quilification__c FROM Inquery__c  WHERE Download__c = False]){

   recordString = inquery.id+','+inquery.First_Name__c+','+inquery.Last_Name__c+','+inquery.Email__c +','+inquery.Quilification__c +'\n';
   finalstr = finalstr +recordString;

  }

    blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(finalstr);

   return null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set this up so that it either attaches the csv to a record in Salesforce or you could even set it up to email the file to you as an attachment.  I have done something similar in the past

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
mail.setUseSignature(false);
mail.setToAddresses(new String[] { 'user@domain.com' });
mail.setSubject('My subject');
mail.setSenderDisplayName('SalesForce Admin');

blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(finalstr);
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
attach.setContentType('application/pdf');
attach.setFileName('myAttachment');
attach.setInline(false);
attach.Body = csvBlob ;

mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attach }); 
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

Comment: May not be exactly what your looking for, but definitely is a way to get the information.  And it seems like this might be something you schedule, so you could schedule the job and it could email you the results daily, weekly, etc.

Comment: Yes I think this is how I will do it, you know I don't think you can download automatically in APEX, it has to be an email, saved as a document, or made available as a web link. I have only done this with Visual Force

Comment: I guess I can add an inputField next to the button, so that the user can provide an email they want the CSV file to be sent to

Comment: Do you know how to call the People object, not the Account object. The one that has all the administrators?

Comment: Hmmm I don't off the top of my head.